# Sort Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Okay, I have seen this:
[Sort array of objects by string property value in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sorting-objects-in-an-array-by-a-field-value-in-javascript)
Now, my problem is that I want sort the array by a field value in dependence of an external int value.

The Int value represents a number of persons for a reservation, the objects in the array are the tables with the seats.

Now, when I got a Reservation with 4 persons the array should beginn with the object where Seats are equal to my Int (the 4 persons) or the nearest higher one. The next ones should be i.e. 6 and 8. Objects with Seats are smaller then my Int should listed at the end (when 4 persons want a reservation, I dont need tables with 2 Seats). I hop its a bit cleare now.

```
{
    Area: "Bar",
    Seats: 2,
    Id : 1
},{
    Area: "Outside",
    Seats: 8,
    Id : 2
},{
    Area: "Room",
    Seats: 4,
    Id : 3
},{
    Area: "Floor",
    Seats: 2,
    Id : 4
},{
    Area: "Room",
    Seats: 6,
    Id : 5
}
```

Okay, here is my solution:

```
        res.sort(function (a, b) {
            if ((a.Seats < goal)  &&  (b.Seats < goal)) {
                return b.Seats - a.Seats;
            }
            if (a.Seats < goal) {
                return 1;
            }
            if (b.Seats < goal) {
                return -1;
            }
            return a.Seats - b.Seats;
        });
```

Comment: @Juhana How does that answer deal with the special case of the field value matching the int variable?

Comment: You should fix your spelling mistakes and show what you have already tried. It's hard to understand what you're aiming to do.

Comment: I don't understand the ordering of the items that don't match the goal. It looks random.

Comment: @Barmar It's reasonably close enough to solve the problem. If the OP doesn't manage it completely, it should get them partway through and they can show the effort they've made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var goal = 4;
array.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.Seats == goal) {
        return -1;
    } else if (b.Seats == goal) {
        return 1;
    } else { // If neither matches the goal, order them by Seats
        return a.Seats - b.Seats;
    }
});
```